# Validating dropdown menu in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, validation, select

I have the following code that validates only when the control moves away from the given `select` element, that is the border of the `select` element does either red or green only when the given `select` is tabbed away or the mouse cursor has moved away from the given `select` element

```
<select class="form-control input-xsmall select-inline" ng-class="{'invalid': form.year.$dirty && currentYear=='Year', 'valid': form.year.$dirty && currentYear != 'Year'}" data-ng-model="currentYear" name="year">
    <option>Year</option>
    <option ng-repeat="year in years" value="{{year}}">{{year}}</option>
</select>
```

What could I do to show the user either the green or the red border based on the validity of the select box while he/she is actually setting the value of the `option` element but has made the select element `$dirty` or `!$pristine`.

Could somebody help me with it?

Comment: Are you using AngularJs 1.3.x or 1.2.x?

Comment: @JoseM: AngularJS 1.2.21

Comment: In 1.3 there is a `$touched` property that you can use, but there isn't anything similar by default in 1.2, although you can make  your own directive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add you own "touched" property to the `year` by using `ng-blur` and then use that "touched" property to add the right class

```
<select class="form-control input-xsmall select-inline" 
  ng-class="{'invalid': form.year.isTouched && currentYear=='Year', 'valid': form.year.isTouched && currentYear != 'Year'}" 
  ng-blur="form.year.isTouched = true"
  data-ng-model="currentYear" 
  name="year">
    <option>Year</option>
    <option ng-repeat="year in years" value="{{year}}">{{year}}</option>
</select>
```

See this sample plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Wpz27yBw8OXSaYfpkP3z?p=preview